LIvewire 3 using wire:navigate failed
I use livewire 3 to build a form using dynamic element. So I can add multiple row element inside my form.
When I run on Manual Page Reload or navigate link click (page reload) without wire:navigate it run smoothly.
But when I use wire:navigate for the link, I found error when initial datepicker. My datepicker can multiple elements, because my form can add dynamically using add button and I must init for using this.
The error is when I navigate to another page, and back to page using datepicker, error like

Uncaught TypeError: window.Livewire.find(...) is undefined

How to fix this?
My view markup and code is here :
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" wire:click="addRow">Add New</button>

<script>
function goBack(e) {
    window.history.back();
}
</script>


@script
<script>

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    console.log("DOMContentLoaded");
    initializeDatepickers();
});

Livewire.hook('element.init', ({ component, el }) => {
    console.log("element.init");
    if (document.querySelectorAll('[id^="date_"]').length) {
        initializeDatepickers();
    }
});

function initializeDatepickers() {
    // Check if rows exist in the Livewire component
    const rows = @this.get('rows');
    if (!rows || !Array.isArray(rows)) {
        return;
    }

    // Iterate through each row and initialize datepicker
    rows.forEach((row, index) => {
        const datepickerId = `#date_${index}`;
        const $datepickerElement = $(datepickerId);

        // Ensure the datepicker element exists before initializing
        if ($datepickerElement.length) {
            // Destroy existing datepicker to avoid conflicts
            if ($datepickerElement.data('datepicker')) {
                $datepickerElement.datepicker('destroy');
            }
            $datepickerElement.datepicker({
                todayHighlight: true,
                orientation: "bottom left",
                autoclose: true,
                format: "dd-mm-yyyy"
            }).on("changeDate", function (e) {
                @this.set(`rows.${index}.date`, e.format());
            });
        }
    });
}

// Initialize the single datepicker
$('#tanggal_ajuan').datepicker({
    todayHighlight: true,
    orientation: "bottom left",
    autoclose: true,
    format: "dd-mm-yyyy"
}).on("changeDate", function (e) {
    $wire.tanggal_ajuan = e.format();
});
</script>
@endscript

My component code :
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Kontrak;

use App\Models\Outlet;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;
use Livewire\Attributes\Title;
use Livewire\Attributes\Validate;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class EventKontrak extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;

    #[Title('Kontrak Event')]

    public $outlet = null;
    public $kelas_event = "";
    public $tanggal_ajuan = "";
    public $nama_talent = "";
    public $tipe_event = "";
    public $publikasi_event = "";

    public $rows = [];

    protected function rules()
    {
        $rules = [
            'kelas_event' => 'required',
            'tanggal_ajuan' => 'required',
            'nama_talent' => 'required',
            'tipe_event' => 'required',
            'publikasi_event' => 'required|file',
            'rows.*.pic_event' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'rows.*.date' => 'required|date',
            'rows.*.day' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'rows.*.venue' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'rows.*.tier' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'rows.*.ro' => 'nullable|string|max:255',
            'rows.*.ao' => 'nullable|string|max:255',
            'rows.*.brand' => 'nullable|string|max:255',
            'rows.*.jam_kerja' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'rows.*.team' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'rows.*.fp' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'rows.*.tl' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'rows.*.wd' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'rows.*.car' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'rows.*.target_contact' => 'required|integer',
            'rows.*.target_trial' => 'required|integer',
            'rows.*.agency' => 'required|string|in:KOMPLIT,OHP',
            'rows.*.jenis_event' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'rows.*.note' => 'nullable|string|max:255',
            'rows.*.keterangan_event' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'rows.*.keterangan' => 'required|string|max:255',
        ];

        return $rules;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.kontrak.event-kontrak');
    }

    public function mount($uuid)
    {
        $this->outlet = Outlet::with(['detail', 'regional', 'area', 'horecaGroup', 'brand', 'installationUnitBranding'])
            ->whereUuid($uuid)
            ->firstOrFail();

        $defaultRo = $this->outlet->regional->name;
        $defaultAo = $this->outlet->area->name;
        $defaultBrand = $this->outlet->brand->merek;

        $this->rows[] = $this->initializeRow($defaultRo, $defaultAo, $defaultBrand);
    }

    private function initializeRow($ro = '', $ao = '', $brand = '')
    {
        return [
            'pic_event' => '',
            'date' => '',
            'day' => '',
            'venue' => '',
            'tier' => '',
            'ro' => $ro,
            'ao' => $ao,
            'brand' => $brand,
            'jam_kerja' => '',
            'team' => '',
            'fp' => '',
            'tl' => '',
            'wd' => '',
            'car' => '',
            'target_contact' => '',
            'target_trial' => '',
            'agency' => '',
            'jenis_event' => '',
            'note' => 'ON THE EVENT',
            'keterangan_event' => '',
            'keterangan' => '',
        ];
    }

    public function addRow()
    {
        // Get the default value for 'ro'
        $defaultRo = $this->outlet->regional->name;
        $defaultAo = $this->outlet->area->name;
        $defaultBrand = $this->outlet->brand->merek;

        // Add a new row with the default value
        $this->rows[] = $this->initializeRow($defaultRo, $defaultAo, $defaultBrand);
    }

    public function removeRow($index)
    {
        unset($this->rows[$index]);
        $this->rows = array_values($this->rows); // Re-index the array
    }

    public function submit()
    {
        $validated = $this->validate([
            'rows.*.pic_event' => 'required|string',
            'rows.*.date' => 'required|date',
            'rows.*.day' => 'required|string',
            'rows.*.venue' => 'required|string',
            'rows.*.tier' => 'required|string',
            'rows.*.jam_kerja' => 'required|string',
            'rows.*.team' => 'required|string',
            'rows.*.fp' => 'required|string',
            'rows.*.tl' => 'required|string',
            'rows.*.wd' => 'required|string',
            'rows.*.car' => 'required|string',
            'rows.*.target_contact' => 'required|integer',
            'rows.*.target_trial' => 'required|integer',
            'rows.*.agency' => 'required|string',
            'rows.*.jenis_event' => 'required|string',
            'rows.*.note' => 'nullable|string',
            'rows.*.keterangan_event' => 'nullable|string',
            'rows.*.keterangan' => 'nullable|string',
        ],[
            'rows.*.pic_event.required' => 'PIC Event field is required.',
            'rows.*.date.required' => 'Date field is required.',
            'rows.*.day.required' => 'Day field is required.',
            'rows.*.venue.required' => 'Venue field is required.',
            'rows.*.tier.required' => 'Tier field is required.',
            'rows.*.jam_kerja.required' => 'Jam Kerja field is required.',
            'rows.*.team.required' => 'Team field is required.',
            'rows.*.fp.required' => 'FP field is required.',
            'rows.*.tl.required' => 'TL field is required.',
            'rows.*.wd.required' => 'WD field is required.',
            'rows.*.car.required' => 'Car field is required.',
            'rows.*.target_contact.required' => 'Target Contact field is required.',
            'rows.*.target_trial.required' => 'Target Trial field is required.',
            'rows.*.agency.required' => 'Agency field is required.',
            'rows.*.jenis_event.required' => 'Jenis Event field is required.',
            'rows.*.note.required' => 'Note field is required.',
            'rows.*.keterangan_event.required' => 'Keterangan Event field is required.',
            'rows.*.keterangan.required' => 'Keterangan field is required.',
        ]);
    }
}

How to make link with wire:navigate and the all elements re-initiated?

When you use wire:navigate, DOMContentLoaded only fires event for first page visit not on sub sequent visits.
https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/navigate#script-evaluation

so how to fix this?
